# Obtaining Figures For Australian GST Business Activity Statement From GNUCash

Tags: taxes, australia, gnucash, gst

I have been entering all my financial records into GNUCash, and now I need to find the most efficient way to extract all the needed figures for the BAS. The *Income & GST Statement* looks like the way to go however it appears only to calculate total sales and GST, and I am uncertain if it can be customised.

Currently, I have created tax tables for Export and GST-Free sales in addition to one for ordinary GST, although this might not be the correct approach. My thought was that I should be able to generate a report that breaks down sales by tax type, or at a pinch generate a report for each tax type, which would allow me to see each subtotal. Doing this has caused the report to calculate purchase tax of $0.00 on many of the sales, so clearly I am doing something wrong.

With respect to purchases, as I have both assets and expenses I would imagine that this needs to be calculated from *Accounts Payable* rather than individual expense and asset accounts, particularly as some of those are not purchases. At this stage, I have only non-capital purchases however for future purchases I would also like to somehow tag each purchase as capital or non-capital.

On the whole, GNUCash seems to be a very good system, so I am hoping enough people are using it to have solved this problem already. I don't want to learn Scheme or run an XSLT stylesheet over my database just to keep the ATO happy. :)

Comment: May be best post your questions on gnucash-user@gnucash.org (an old fashioned mailing list). If you're posting GST-free and GST-able items as different entries in an invoice, the Income&GST Statement does not have the ability to delve into invoice entries. It can however count them separately as separate invoices.

Comment: Wow, Income&GST Statement is fairly useless.

Answer (score 0):

See the wiki:

1. https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Quickstart_Australian_BAS
2. https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Alternate_Australian_GST_setup

Hope this helps.